# Need to return an object with the lowest property value from List of objects

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a list of Customers that looks like this:

```
var customers = new List<Customer>
{
    new Customer { Name = "John", Age = 20 },
    new Customer { Name = "Adam", Age = 30 },
    new Customer { Name = "Joi", Age = 26 }
};
```

What is the best way to return the object of customer with the lowest age?

Comment: What does "best" mean to you? Most efficient? Easiest? Maybe you want to use [`Min()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.min?view=net-6.0)

Comment: efficient I mean , How can I use Min() on list of objects

Comment: Which .NET version are you on? If you are on .NET 6 you can use `MinBy`, `customers.MinBy(c => c.Age)`

Comment: I on version 3.2

Comment: Also important to know is your expected behavior if two people have the same minimum age.

Comment: @WhoAmI - Do keep in mind that the `.OrderBy(c => c.Age).FirstOrDefault()` approach has `O(n.logn)` complexity and it allocates a lot of temporary data. The `Aggregate` or `MinBy` approaches are `O(n)` and create virtually no temporary objects. What did you mean by the "best" way?

Comment: @Enigmativity I got curious and looked it up. [In 3.x it is O(n), not O(nlogn)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/5.0/orderby-firstordefault-complexity-increase). Even after 3.x the implementation changed but is still supposed to be more performant overall.

Comment: @Crowcoder - I didn't think any sort that is better than `O(n.logn)`.

Comment: @Crowcoder - Yep. ["Therefore, any comparison based sorting algorithm must make at least nLog2n comparisons to sort the input array..."](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lower-bound-on-comparison-based-sorting-algorithms/). The `OrderBy` sort is comparison-based.

Comment: @Crowcoder - Ah, but your article is saying that the sort is incomplete and only needs to yield the first element. But it seems like it is back to `O(n.logn)` from 5.0 onwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you would achieve that by ordering objects by age first then returning the first element in the list.
and you can accomplish that by adding this linq query.

```cs
Customer lowestAgeCustomer = Customers.OrderBy(c => c.Age).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 5):

This is most efficient way:

```
var customers = new List<Customer>
{
    new Customer { Name = "John", Age = 20 },
    new Customer { Name = "Adam", Age = 30 },
    new Customer { Name = "Joi", Age = 26 }
};

var youngest = customers.Aggregate((x, y) => x.Age < y.Age ? x : y);
```

That gives me:

[image: youngest]

Or, now with .NET 6.0:

```
var youngest = customers.MinBy(c => c.Age);
```